# 剩一点儿都没地方搁　How is the sentence composed of?

Tags: grammar, usage

I'm newbie in this community. My best regards.

没了冰箱还真不行，每天早上都要去早市买菜，饭也不能多做，**剩一点儿都没地方搁。**

The bolded sentence means "There is no place for conserving the remained foods."

How is the sentence composed of?

It seems "搁" is the adjective of "地方".( the place for conserving ...)
But "搁" is a verb in my textbook and electric dictionary.

Is the sentence equal to this sentence?

剩(饭)一点儿  and 搁没(在)地方(饭)?

How should I understand this sentence?
Why is "都没地方"  in front of "搁"?

Comment: 搁 is a dialect word in Chinese, means 放. 剩一点儿都没地方搁 means 如果饭(做多了吃不完)剩下了, 都没有地方放. or: there is no space to put the leftover in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"搁" is a verb for "to place; to put"

> 剩一点儿(食物)都没地方搁

剩一点儿 = left a little bit

(吃)剩一点儿(**食物**)= left a little bit (of food)

(吃)剩一点儿(食物)**都** = **even** left a little bit (of food)

> "(吃)剩一点儿(食物)都**没地方搁**" = "Even left a little bit (of food), **there's no place to put it**" or "There is no place to put even a little bit of leftover" (*rephrase in common English grammar*)
>
> *The verb "吃" (eat) and the object "饭 or 食物" (food) are omitted because "剩" implied "吃剩"  and the object for "吃剩" (left over) is clearly food*

~

> *Why is "都没地方" in front of "搁"?*

"没地方"(no place to) is the relative/adverbial phrase for  "搁 " (to place). It gives more details on the simple sentence: "搁(食物)"

Comment: Thanks to your explanation, (吃)剩一点儿(食物)都 is  understandable to me.I didn't understand the sentence,neither.But "没地方搁"? I can't understande it clearly or I wonder if I missed searching some points.What is the relation between "搁" and "没地方"?Can  "搁" embelish or decorate "地方" as "to put" from backends?

Comment: @user9402680  "没地方" (no place to) is the adverbial phrase of "搁 (食物)" (place food). It gives more details on the simple sentence: "搁(食物)"

Comment: Oh,I thought "没地方" and "搁" as upside-down.I didn't know "没地方" has an adverbial function.Great, I understood completely.Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm sorry for late, "There is the place "that" put it." or "There is no place "that" put it. You means ,in Chinese, there are many cases (relative pronouns in English grammer)between "nouns" and "verbs (+Common Object)" like that, but "that" is not explicitly.

Comment: it is 没地方 (去) "搁 = "there is no place (to) put"

Comment: 有地方搁 = 有地方(去) 搁 = have place (to) put ; "去" (to)"  here can be omitted in Chinese, but not in English

Comment: @Tanh Ho thanks very much again and again. I absolutely understood.

Answer (score 0):

搁 剩饭 store/keep/put leftover/uneaten food

没了冰箱还真不行，
Not having a fridge is really inconvenient,
每天早上都要去早市买菜，
every day I have to go to the early market to buy vegetables,
饭也不能多做，
also, I can't cook too much (because)
剩一点儿都没地方搁。
I have no place to put the leftovers.

Comment: 菜 in 去早市买菜 is not just vegetables, it refers to "food ingredients for cooking dishes" in general

Comment: yeah, you're right, I'm always in a big hurry, never take time to think carefully. Just some fun here, coz I love the Chinese language!